# What are the differences between the following versions of Guitar Hero?

Tags: version-differences, guitar-hero-live

[Guitar Hero Live: Double Guitar Bundle (Exclusive to Amazon.co.uk) - £105.77](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Guitar-Hero-Live-Controller-PS4/dp/B00ZQB7FME/ref=sr_1_1_twi_gam_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1476353356&sr=8-1&keywords=guitar%2Bhero&th=1)

[Supreme Party Edition (PS4) - £59.99](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Guitar-Hero-Live-Controller-PS4/dp/B01LYGUKU3/ref=sr_1_1_twi_gam_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1476353356&sr=8-1&keywords=guitar%2Bhero&th=1)

The latter is worth double, but I can't see an obvious reason.

Please help me before Amazon manages to adapt to the rapidly collapsing pound.

Comment: I see someone's voted to close, because this doesn't count as a question about videogames. Consider that if the question was "What are the differences between Sonic 1 and Sonic 2", it would already have 5 answers. See the "Related" sidebar for over half a dozen such questions.

Answer (score 1):

The first one (Double Guitar Pack) is the base game and two guitar, nothing else.

The second one is the base game, two guitar (so the Double Guitar Pack), the "Supreme Party" extension (don't know the specifics) and GHTV.